# Multiple map fragment not working with google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, mapfragment

In my new android project there are two tabs. First tab contains a map fragment which shows current location and nearby place lists with markers. And the second tab shows the current location only(Simply a map). But while tab switching no animation happens and it shows only first tabs map fragments and markers it is not loading the second map fragment. what should i do now?

**here is what i am expecting**

[image]

[image]

Comment: FWIW, this sample project demonstrates using multiple `SupportMapFragment` instances within a `ViewPager`, using tabs: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Pager Note that since I have my maps filling the pages, you can only navigate between pages via the tabs -- maps not filling the page would allow traditional `ViewPager` swiping initiated from outside the maps.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Have u succeed in making it work with the new ActionBarCompat ?

Comment: @Poutrathor: I have not tried, as I am not planning on doing much work with ActionBarCompat.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it not better to go with the company support library rather than to stick with one that could stop being updated? Or do you already have too much framework/personal code to do the change? (just curious, I asked and read about it at the time but if I can have your feel on it ?)

Comment: @CommonsWare I ll try updating and do a dummy app from that sample, is it okay?

Comment: @Poutrathor: "Is it not better to go with the company support library rather than to stick with one that could stop being updated?" -- IMHO, it is better to start planning on abandoning API Level 10 and below. Rewriting an existing app to switch action bar backports is a waste of time. If you have additional concerns, ask a fresh SO question, rather than hijacking somebody else's question for a topic completely unrelated to that question.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, thanks ! Sry for the hijack